# avoid waiting time in setInterval jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm working in this script where the `li` content shows up in the `input` every 10 seconds. it works ok...but....

I have to wait 10 seconds for the code to start executing after the initial `button` click...

how do I avoid this behaviour? I just want the script starts right away.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var items = $(".menu li"), idx = 0;

  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var currText = items.eq(idx).text()
    if (idx < items.length - 1) idx++;
    else idx = 0;
    
    
    $("#show").val(currText);
 
  }, 10000);
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>show li in order every 10 seconds</button>

<input type=text id="show" />
<ul class="menu">

  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that *has* that interval - and call it!
Don't forget to use `.one()` instead of `.on()`

```js
var items = $(".menu li"), $show = $('#show'), idx = 0, timer = null;

function doIt () {
  var currText = items.eq(idx).text()
  if (idx < items.length - 1) idx++;
  else clearInterval(timer);
  $show.val(currText);
  timer = setInterval(doIt, 1000);
}

$("button").one("click", doIt);
```

```css
input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>show li in order every 10 seconds</button>

<input type=text id="show" />
<ul class="menu">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: nice solution. is there another way to make it work without creating a function? because this is a pretty simplified version of my current code...and If I create a new function...everything is going to move....

Comment: @max no, anyways you either have to copy-paste your code somewhere else or wrap it - which is not a terrifying task. It can take you almost 3sec.

Comment: I understand the point. well thank you. I think its quite enought.